# How to tilt hover in CSS

Tags: html, css

I try to stylize hover for the header.

It shows like this.
[image: image 1]

And I want to make it look like this:
[image: image 2]

Even when I tried skew, the text was also tilting with it.

Help will be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```css
.hvr-link {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.hvr-link:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #424141;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50%;
  transform-origin: 50%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.hvr-link:hover,
.hvr-link:focus,
.hvr-link:active {
  color: white;
}

.hvr-link:hover:before,
.hvr-link:focus:before,
.hvr-link:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-7 col-sm-12">
  <div class="nav-outer clearfix menu-bg">
    <!--main-menu start-->
    <nav class="main-menu">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse clearfix">
        <ul class="navigation clearfix">
          <li class="hvr_link"><a class="hvr-link" href="#top">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="hvr-link" href="#service">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a class="hvr-link" href="#">About</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="hvr-link" href="#aboutmy">About</a></li>
              <li><a class="hvr-link" href="#teammy">Team</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a class="hvr-link" href="#portfoliomy">Portfolio</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="hvr-link2" href="#propertymy">Properties</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="hvr-link2" href="#contactmy">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </nav>
    <!--main-menu end-->

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In this context, it can be a little bit tricky because you have to put the link text in a span element in order to be able to achieve this.

Check the snippet below, a quick explanation:

What `transform: skewX(20deg);` does to `.menu li a` is basically tilt the link as you require. The problem there is that that tilts the entire element, text included. That's why you use a `span` inside your link and apply a counter tilt to that span using `transform: skewX(-20deg);`. It's basically resulting in a final 0 degree tilt. The rest of the styles I added just to simulate your requirements.

Also, it's important that the `a` elements use `inline-block` if you're not using float or `block` if you're using float, otherwise they are not affected by the tilt. Same applies to the inner `span` element.

It would look something like this:

```css
.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  background: #3d424a;
}

.menu li a {
  color: #c3c5c7;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: skewX(20deg);
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 2rem;
  transition: background 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.menu li a span {
  transform: skewX(-20deg);
  display: block;
}

.menu li a:hover {
  background: #fda539;
  color: #3d424a;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#"><span>Home</span></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><span>About</span></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><span>Contact</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can hover and create images. I added in the text to show you how to *unskew* the text as well so it doesn't get messed up on hovering.

```css
.navigation {
    transform: skew(20deg);
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
  }
  ul {
      list-style-type: none;
  }

  ul li a {
      display: block;
      transform: skew(-20deg);
      text-align: center;
  }

  li:hover {
      background: orange;
  }
```

```html
  <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-12">
    <div class="nav-outer clearfix menu-bg"> 
      <!--main-menu start-->
      <nav class="main-menu">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse clearfix">
          <ul class="navigation clearfix">
            <li class="hvr_link"><a class="hvr-link" href="#top">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="hvr-link" href="#service">Services</a>
            </li>
             <li class="dropdown"><a class="hvr-link" href="#">About</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a class="hvr-link" href="#aboutmy">About</a></li>
                <li><a class="hvr-link" href="#teammy">Team</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a class="hvr-link" href="#portfoliomy">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="hvr-link2" href="#propertymy">Properties</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="hvr-link2" href="#contactmy">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </nav>
      <!--main-menu end--> 
      
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: The text font is changing, i dont wants it to get changed.

Comment: @DaniyalKhanII look at my snippet. it doesn't change. You have unskew it to keep it from doing that.

Comment: please explain how, help will be highlyy appreciated

Comment: you only provided your css. I have no idea what your html looks like.

Comment: @DaniyalKhanII Look at my snippet again. I updated it with your HTML.

Comment: @Brandon The only possible issue with skewing the entire navigation is that if he requires to add let's say a search bar he'd have to write separate styles for that.

Answer (score -2):

```
  #parallelogram {
      width: 150px;
      height: 100px;
      transform: skew(20deg);
      background: red;
  }
```

https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/#parallelogram-shape

Comment: The code i provided, can u please tell me where to edit as am i a complete newbie. thanks

Comment: Please add explanation to your answer showing how to apply the styles to the OP's code, or (even better), create a Stack Snippet (icon looks like `<>` in the toolbar) with a complete example.